# asp.net mvc displayFor does not show child entity value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I'm a novice, so I guess my issue is trivial somehow.

I created a simple DB with CodeFirst. I have an entity named `Person` and another named `Location`. `Person` has a `ForeignKey` property named `LocationId` and another property of type `Location` for reference purpose.

I created a view in which there's a form by which I able to create new `Person` records.

One of the form fields is a DropDownList for the 'Location' of a person. It takes an Id value and assign it to the `LocationId` property of `Person`.

This view is referencing to a `create` Controller action that receives  a `Person` as an argument, and makes a binding to the form fields with the `person` properties. Then, it performs a `SaveChanges()` into `DBContext` and redirect to another Action named `details` with the specific Person 'Id`.

`Details` makes a `find` on the recieved Id and sends the result (Person) to a view for presentation.

Here's my problem:
I try to display the Location txt of the specific 'Person' which I passed, and get nothing.
I do it by:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Location.LocationValue)
```

The model of course is a 'person'.
Why don't I get any value for this?

Here's the code:

```
   public class Person
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set;
        public string LocationId { get; set; }
        ...
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
     }

     public class Location
        {

           public int LocationId { get; set; }
           public string LocationValue { get; set; }

           public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
         }

    public ActionResult Detailes(int id)
    {
        Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);

        return View(person);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddPerson(Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Persons.Add(person);
            db.SaveChanges();   
            return RedirectToAction("Detailes", new {id = person.PersonId});
        }  
        return View(GetAddPersonViewModel());
     }
```

The model here is a viewmodel for the form

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Person.LocationId, Model.LocationsList)
```

And again, the presentation of the 'details' view:

```
     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Location.LocationValue)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of location value? Why aren't you just using a `Html.TextBoxFor`?

Comment: If you post the Person/Location classes and configuration classes where you define foreign keys would be helpful to identify the problem

Comment: 'LocationValue' is of string type. It holds the name of the location. TextBox is for input, I need a presentation of it's value only..

Comment: does Person class has a Location property? or not?

Comment: Jayanga: yes, as mentioned...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may happen if you have not put any configuration to map the relation between Person and Location. here is a sample configuration class

```
public class LocationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Location>
    {
        public LocationConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(a => a.Id);
            HasMany(location => location.Persons).WithOptional(person => person.Location).
               HasForeignKey(person => person.LocationId);
        }
    }
```

and add this configuration to your context as follows

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
    {

       // your DBSets and contructors, etc


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LocationConfiguration());            
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }


    }
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks. Truth is I prety much followed MvcMusicStore tutorial. If you look there, there's no need for the map configuration... You may also notice, from the diagram of the DB that these connections are self interpreted.

Comment: Try this and check whether your program works. If this helps please mark this as answer :)

Comment: I did. I got this error msg:  \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationConstraint: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'LocationId' on entity 'Person' does not match the type of property 'LocationId' on entity 'Location' in the referential constraint 'Location_Persons'. The red marked line is "Line 32:             @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Person.LocationId, Model.LocationsList)"

Comment: Problem solved. Error msg made me realzie I should change FK type to int.